# Creating a filter to check a case for a letter in a field in the json body in REST assured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I have a request in the form of json,which looks like this.

```
{"User":{"email":"test@test.com","FName":"fname"}}
```

When I try to send it via REST assured ,the `U` in the `User` is seen to change its case.i.e. changes to a lower case.

To send the request I have created my own serialized classes. The end-point is seen like this:

```
{"user":{"email":"test@test.com","FName":"fname"}}
```

but somehow it is not changing the case of the remaining fields.I don't knwo why this is happening.

I've even tried to create a filter for a request specification,but couldn't go any further with that too. I also then thought of first converting the serialized object to a gson,and then check the case of the User, still no luck.

Error I get is:

> The class, User,does not match the payload object for payload.

Please note I am trying to use the service of another team,so I really don't have an access to their code-base(Although not needed).Observe the space between the first `,` and user in the above message, is it worth noting?

Comment: In the English language, a comma followed by a space is proper formatting. So... I'm confused now

Comment: @JClassic: agreed,that was just what I observed. But,still more confusing is change in the case of a letter.Even though the serialized class has it correctly declared.

Comment: i am also use rest assured, but no Situation liking you said. everything is ok.
may be , you can check the version(mine 2.3.0) you using.

Comment: @CHmoonKa: My version is: 2.3.2. I know a weird situationSo, what I am planning to do is something like this. Create a method by name convert,pass the field User which is a  object of another class. Inside the convert() method,I make the object's name to be a string,check for the first character,and convert to upper if it is not.  And then return the newly formatted name. Is this a good method?

Comment: i also test 2.3.2, it does not like you said. everything is right. may be your other component has Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got away with it by converting the object(JSON) into a JSON string/payload.
And while passing it as a form parameter,passed the string/payload.
Somehow,still couldn't figure out why the formparameter/formparam option in RESTAssured did not allow the serialized object to go through. But,anyway got around it this time.

Thanks for the suggestions all.